# C# ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed

Tags: c#

```
private void comT_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comT.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT ISNULL(substring(MAX(tCode),3,2),'00')
            FROM Teacher
            WHERE dCode = '" + comT.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'", MUControlClass.con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();  <--HERE IS ERROR **"ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed."**
            if (dr[0].ToString() != "00")
            {
                int dugaar = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]) + 1;
                if (dugaar > 9)
                {
                    msk.Text = comT.SelectedValue.ToString() + dugaar.ToString();
                }
                else
                    msk.Text = comT.SelectedValue.ToString() + "0" + dugaar.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                msk.Text = comT.SelectedValue.ToString() + "01";
            }
            dr.Close();
        }
    }
```

ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed. Error

Comment: Error message is pretty clear.  `MUControlClass.con` is not open.

Comment: You should probably use `using {...}` blocks for your query calls, and always create a new connection when doing so.  See [in a “using” block is a SqlConnection closed on return or exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4717789/719186) for an example.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like you're trying to share a single connection object across multiple methods. This is very often the wrong thing to do. Share the connection *string* but not the connection object. Create the object close to usage instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *immediate* error is that the connection is not open, as it told you; so ... *open it*; however, there are a **lot** of other serious problems here - most notably "SQL injection", but also non-disposed objects. You can fix SQL injection by using parameters, and the non-disposed problem with lots of `using`, but: I *strongly* suggest you make use of tools that will help you get this right by default. For example:

```cs
private void comT_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comT.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
        {
            string max = conn.QuerySingle<string>(@"
SELECT ISNULL(substring(MAX(tCode),3,2),'00')
FROM Teacher
WHERE dCode = @dCode", new { dCode = comT.SelectedValue.ToString() });
            if (max != null)
            {
                // your parse/etc logic
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is:

- moving our connection lifetime to be local to this method, which will stop a *lot* of connection usage problems
- using ["Dapper"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) to provide the `QuerySingle<T>` code
- which means you *don't* need to mess with commands or readers
- adding parameter usage via `@dCode` and the `new { dCode = ... }` usage

Note it might *look* like we've still not opened the connection here, but Dapper is happy to do that for us; if it is *given* a closed connection, it opens the connection *for the duration of the query only*.

Comment: One of the reasons I use Stored Procedures. It _forces_ the developper to use parameters.

Comment: @jscarle I've seen people do `cmd.CommandText = "EXEC myProc @id=" + id + ", @name='" + name + "'";` - never under-estimate the ability to screw up; broadly (but not exactly) related: https://blog.marcgravell.com/2017/12/dapper-prepared-statements-and-car-tyres.html

Comment: @jscarle Not to mention stored procedures that takes in parameters but use it inside to create dynamic SQL statements using string concatenations.... [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40603360/3094533)

Answer (score 1):

Wherever the connection is created in `MUControlClass` you need to call `con.Open()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection is not opened.

Simplified flow of connection and interaction with database is like this:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
{
    con.Open() // You do not open this one so it returns that error
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(yourSqlCommand, con))
    {
        using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if(dr.Read())
            {
                // Do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> We do not need to do close/destroy anything as long as it is wrapped in `using` since they all implements `IDisposable`